# r choosing date based on a conditon

Tags: r, date, datatable, dplyr, subset

I have a dataset with  three columns, Id, Code, Date.

```
Id          Code                 Date
70329       CD_1020              2004-08-25
70329       DSW_46               2005-01-18
70329       AS_712               2009-09-11
1194167     CK_45                2005-10-13
1194167     CD_412               2012-04-12
1194167     DSW_99               2004-08-16
1194167     CD_456               2010-04-18
```

For each `Id`, the column `Code` will contain many different code value, but it will always contain either value **DSW_46** or **DSW_99**. These two values, either DSW_46 or DSW_99 will be present regardless of what other code values exists for each id.

The goal is to create a fourth column based on this criteria.

step1 : Fore each `Id`, capture the date where the row contains either DSW_46 or DSW_99.

step2  :

a) If the there are rows earlier than the DSW_46 or DSW_99 rows for that `Id`, then store the date that contains values either DSW_46 or DSW_99. For example: In the case of Id 70329, there is row with value DSW_46 and the corresponding date is 2005-01-18, however there is a row prior to 2005-01-18 for that id. So the new date column should store date 2005-01-18

b) If there are no rows earlier than the rows with either DSW_46 or DSW_99 values, then store the date of the next observation for that ID. For example: In the case of ID 1194167, row containing DSW_99 has a date value of 2004-08-16 and this is the earliest. There is nothing prior to this for this id (1194167). So the new date column should store date 2005.10.13 which is next date after 2004-08-16.

The final expected dataset is as shown below

```
Id          Code                 Date         NewDate
70329       CD_1020              2004-08-25   2005-01-18
70329       DSW_46               2005-01-18   2005-01-18 
70329       AS_712               2009-09-11   2005-01-18
1194167     CK_45                2005-10-13   2005-10-13
1194167     CD_412               2012-04-12   2005-10-13
1194167     DSW_99               2004-08-16   2005-10-13
1194167     CD_456               2010-04-18   2005-10-13
```

Hope this makes sense. Any assistance on how to accomplish this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `dplyr` with `ifelse`

library(dplyr)

```
df$Date=as.character(df$Date)
df1=df %>%arrange(Date)%>%group_by(Id)%>% 
    dplyr::mutate(NewDate = ifelse(sum(Date>=Date[Code%in%c('DSW_46','DSW_99')])==length(Date),Date[2] ,Date[Code%in%c('DSW_46','DSW_99')]))

output


Id    Code       Date    NewDate
    <int>   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
1 1194167  DSW_99 2004-08-16 2005-10-13
2   70329 CD_1020 2004-08-25 2005-01-18
3   70329  DSW_46 2005-01-18 2005-01-18
4 1194167   CK_45 2005-10-13 2005-10-13
5   70329  AS_712 2009-09-11 2005-01-18
6 1194167  CD_456 2010-04-18 2005-10-13
7 1194167  CD_412 2012-04-12 2005-10-13
```

Comment: glad it help !~

Answer (score 0):

Another `dplyr` solution, using `summarise` and `left_join`.

```
dt <- read.table(text = "Id          Code                 Date
70329       CD_1020              2004-08-25
                 70329       DSW_46               2005-01-18
                 70329       AS_712               2009-09-11
                 1194167     CK_45                2005-10-13
                 1194167     CD_412               2012-04-12
                 1194167     DSW_99               2004-08-16
                 1194167     CD_456               2010-04-18",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Id)

dt3 <- dt2 %>%
  filter(Code %in% c("DSW_46", "DSW_99")) %>%
  summarise(Date_DSW = min(Date))

dt4 <- dt2 %>%  
  filter(!Code %in% c("DSW_46", "DSW_99")) %>%
  summarise(Date_min = min(Date))

dt5 <- dt2 %>%
  left_join(dt3, by = "Id") %>%
  left_join(dt4, by = "Id") %>%
  mutate(NewDate = if_else(Date_DSW > Date_min, Date_DSW, Date_min)) %>%
  select(Id, Code, Date, NewDate)
```